# Can the time complexity be reduced from O(n^2) to O(n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have a sequence A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, A<sub>3</sub>.....A<sub>N</sub>. For each valid `i`, the `count value` of the element A<sub>i</sub> is the number of valid indices `j < i` such that A<sub>j</sub> is divisible by A<sub>i</sub>.

I want to know the maximum `count value`.

I did it using the following code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):             #number of test cases
    n = int(input())                      # no. of elements in A  
    A = list(map(int, input().split()))
    count_arr = []                      # array with count value
    for i in range(n):
        b = A[:i]
        b = [x%A[i] for x in b]
        count_arr.append(b.count(0))
    print(max(count_arr))
```

> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 1
> 7 
> 8 1 28 4 2 6 7
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> A<sub>5</sub> = 2 divides 4, 28 and 8, so its count value is 3. There
>   is no element in `count_arr` with a higher count value.

The time complexity would be O(n<sup>2</sup>). I want to know if this problem could be solved in a faster way, perhaps with O(n) complexity.

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example (including dummy data) so that we can work from something that is able to actually execute ?

Comment: yes, it can be solved in O(n). Think more about using a few variables in your algo to store certain things that will help you know the final count.

Comment: @smarie Question edited.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay If you could be more explicit about ```storing certain things```, it'd help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an easy method to find out what are the divisors of a number, you only need to traverse your sequence once:

```
def divisors(num):
    yield 1

    for i in range (2, int(num ** .5) + 1):
        if num % i: # not divisible
            continue 
        yield i
        if i**2 != num:
            yield num // i
```

Is a rather naive method of finding the divisors of a number.

If the original number also needs to be included, you can change the `divisors` to

```
def divisors(num):
    yield 1
    if num == 1:
        return
    yield num
    for i in range (2, int(num ** .5) + 1):
        if num % i: # not divisible
            continue 
        yield i
        if i**2 != num:
            yield num // i
```

Then you need a structure to hold how much time each divisor is seen already. A `collections.Counter` is ideal for this purpose

```
def previous_multiples(sequence):
    counter = Counter()
    for i in sequence:
        yield counter[i]
        counter.update(divisors(i))
```

This yield for each number how much previous numbers were divisible by it. Then it updates the divisors with its own divisors

This can be called like this `max(previous_multiples(sequence))`

This trades in the time it takes to find the divisors of each number vs the time it takes to check each element vs all previous elements.

Comment: I think this approach might fail if duplicates are present.

Comment: how so? Can you give a counter example?

Comment: If the sequence ```[2, 4 , 6 , 2]``` is passed, the ```max(previous_multiples(sequence))``` returns 2, which should be 3 instead.

Comment: Then you just need to change `divisors` to also include the original number. I've edited my answer with the fix

Comment: I did some research and came across the ```any()``` function. I tried to solve the problem using it but turns out I still end up with O(n^2) time complexity. So it seems, I should use this approach until I figure out some different way.
Thanks.